# can't connect to the Ubuntu server

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh, 22.04

I am trying to connect to my Ubuntu server using ssh command on Ubuntu 22.04
after about a minute it shows me a timeout error
I tried disabling firewall or this command :

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

and I'm sure that my server is not filtered, because I get its ping.
also I tried putty in windows to connect but it can't get connected too.
I talked to server provider, they told me my server is active and doesn't have problem.

I also tried connecting with another IP address(if the PC Id was got banned, because I had fail2ban system activated on the server)

all of them didn't work, and I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Assuming you have a web interface, you could use `tcpdump` on your server to check if the `ssh` connection requests reach the server.

Comment: If you have fail2ban activated, maybe that's why you can't connect ..